# How can I filter more than one thing out of return from API in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am including my code that I have implemented to filter through `sortedDiscipline` names.

The problem I am having --even though it is filtering through the names-- is after the `IndexPath.row` is changed from the filtering, the image is incorrect for the current game, and also the cell that is populated cannot be selected because the `didSelectRow` does not follow the broken `IndexPath`.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class AllGamesTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {


    let urlFront = "https://www.toornament.com/disciplines/"
    let urlImagePath = "/img/icon-48x48-medium.png"
    var selectedRow: Int?
    var newArray = [String]()
    var filteredGames = [String]()
    var searchController: UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.minimal
        // Include the search bar within the navigation bar.
        navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1137254902, green: 0.168627451, blue: 0.1764705882, alpha: 1)
        self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1137254902, green: 0.168627451, blue: 0.1764705882, alpha: 1)
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)

//        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (searchController?.isActive)!{
            return filteredGames.count
        }else{
            return ApiManager.shared.sortedDisipline.count

        }
    }
    let getID = ApiManager.shared.disciplinesID



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "allGamesCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 29.0/255.0, green: 43.0/255.0, blue: 45.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        let disciplineid = ApiManager.shared.sortedDisciplineID[indexPath.row]

        if (searchController?.isActive)!{
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredGames[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 165.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "\(disciplineid).png")


        }else{

            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 165.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
            cell.textLabel?.text = ApiManager.shared.sortedDisipline[indexPath.row]
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "\(disciplineid).png")

        }

        return cell

    }
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filteredGames.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        //filter through the all games
        filteredGames = ApiManager.shared.sortedDisipline.filter {
            game in

            game.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())

        }
       // if searchController.searchBar.text != ""{

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
   // }


         override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        print(indexPath.row)
        let DisciplineID = filteredGames[indexPath.row]
        TournamentStore.shared.currentDisciplineId = DisciplineID
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "tournamentList", sender: self)
    } else {
        let DisciplineID = ApiManager.shared.sortedDisciplineID[indexPath.row]

        print("\(DisciplineID) \("did on click")")
        TournamentStore.shared.currentDisciplineId = DisciplineID
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "tournamentList", sender: self)
    }


}
```

Comment: The reason your selection is crashing or incorrect is in your `didSelectRowAt indexPath` if you are searching you are not using the filtered list to get the ID. which is also why the image is wrong, you need to get the ID out of the filtered array if sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to solve the issues.

- Do not use separate arrays for `disciplinesID` and `sortedDisipline`
- Use the  class or struct representing `discipline` for both the data source array and the `filteredGames` array.
- Get the `disciplineid` always directly from the `discipline` object. (**Solves the image issue**)
- In `didSelectRowAt` get the object depending on `searchController?.isActive` like in the other methods (**solves the `indexPath` issue**)

---

PS: Initialize the search controller lazily and non-optional. That avoids a lot of question and exclamation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Migrated from my comment for more explanation.

The reason your selection is incorrect is in your `didSelectRowAt indexPath` if you are searching you are not using the filtered list to get the ID. This is also why the image is wrong when reloading, you need to get the ID out of the filtered array if sorting

Something like this:

```
let id: String
if filtering {
    id =  filteredGames[indexPath.row]
} else {
    id = ApiManager.shared.sortedDisciplineID[indexPath.row])
}
```

then use that id for the image and for opening it. Essentially when you sort you are changing how the names match up with the row ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Most of my problem was that 
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation was set to true....it needed to be false.